# Braintree ios + java transaction API returns 403

Tags: braintree

Just started the project. The client side app is the Braintree demo app. I modified it to point to my server running on localhost

Here is what I'm doing.

1. ios app makes an request to server to get a token
2. server uses method below to get a token from Braintree and sends back to server

   BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway(
                 Environment.SANDBOX,
                 merchantAccountId,
                 ".........",
                 "............."
               );
   String token = gateway.clientToken().generate();  // Braintree did return a token
3. ios demo app creates a nonce with the drop-in view
4. ios demo app sends the nonce to the server

   // nonce sends to server 71a89c9d-6ca7-4804-a895-b0e7564425c6
5. server calls Braintree API with code below

   ```
       TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest()
       .amount(new BigDecimal(19.0f))
       .merchantAccountId(merchantAccountId)
       .paymentMethodNonce(nonce)
       .options()
           .submitForSettlement(true)
           .done()
       .channel("MyShoppingCartProvider");
       Result<Transaction> result = gateway.transaction().sale(request);
       return result;
   ```

The last step got 403 com.braintreegateway.exceptions.AuthorizationException exception from Braintree. The xml from the error stream is Unauthorized. The input stream from Braintree says "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/vb38crtnzn77b9ys/transactions"

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that there are two IDs. One is merchantId and the other merchantAccountId. The server sends back the merchantId back to client. And later for charging, use merchantAccountId.

Comment: Solved my problem in 2020. Now I can go to bed.